# Is it always the case that a real number multiplied by a complex number outputs a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it always the case that a real number multiplied by a complex number outputs a complex number? It is a general question I had and think it is true but am quite unsure. I took the form of a real number and multiplied it times a + bi where b isn't zero, and it seems to be true to me, but I wonder if maybe I am wrong.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, do you define _complex_ to exclude _real_? (Technically, it doesn't.) If you don't, this is a special case of complex numbers being closed under multiplication; if you do, you need the real number to be non-zero.

Comment: Yep, $0(a+bi) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can define complex numbers as ordered pairs of real numbers.

Precisely, here it is its explicit definition:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C} = \{(x,y) : (x\in\mathbb{R})\wedge(y\in\mathbb{R})\}
\end{align*}

Within this set, we define addition as
\begin{align*}
(a,b) + (c,d) = (a + c,b + d)
\end{align*}
and multiplication as
\begin{align*}
(a,b)(c,d) = (ac - bd,ad + bc)
\end{align*}

It can be shown that such set endowed with above-mentioned operations is a field indeed.

As to your question, suppose $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Such number can be identified with the complex number $(a,0)$.

Thus, if we take $(c,d)\in\mathbb{C}$, their product results into the expression
\begin{align*}
(a,0)(c,d) = (ac - 0d,ad + 0c) = (ac,ad)
\end{align*}
which clearly belongs to $\mathbb{C}$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: ... and $(ac,ad)$ is "real" only if $ad=0$.  In that case, either $a=0$, and we multiply $(c,d)$ by the real number $0$; or $d=0$, and we multiply $a$ times a real number.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  As Dan Correia points out in the comments, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ (that is, $z$ is a non-real complex number), $$z\cdot 0=0\in\mathbb{R}$$

But for any other real $r$, $$z\cdot r\notin\mathbb{R}$$  The argument for this is simple: if $s\in\mathbb{R}$ is the product $s=z\cdot r$, then $z=\frac{s}{r}$.  But we know the the quotient of two real numbers is real.